# Свойство формы BackgroundImage

Tags: c#

Существует стандартный фон (картинка), имеется так же `MenuStrip` в котором есть закладка Фоны и пункты Земля, Небо, Солнце и т.д.. Как при клике на любой из них менять фон (нужно через ресурсы)
К примеру

```
this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._тут_название);
```

Где взять само название картинки (ресурсов)

Comment: А под каким именем вы добавили картинку в ресурсы? Под тем и доставайте. (Если ответ — ни под каким, то её там и нету, добавьте сначала.)

Comment: Вторая картинка это та - которую нужно отобразить
http://s51.radikal.ru/i133/1305/26/e0d5887ca533.png

Comment: Ненене, это у вас просто каталог, который вы назвали `Resources`. От этого он на ресурсы не отобразился. Добавляйте в ресурсы по-честному, через свойства проекта.

Comment: можно примерчик, как должно выглядить?:

Comment: Ну, вот внизу ответ же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Положить в ресурсы, вестимо...

Свойства проекта -> Вкладка Resources -> Добавление ресурсов...

Или я совсем ничего не понял? ^_^